# Node не является исполняемой программой

Tags: node.js, cmd, npm

Скачал установщик .msi. Но после установки node.js не заработал. Консоль пишет: "node/nmp не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом. При этом все установлено, сама папка с nodejs существует.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Достаточно прописать в переменную среду PATH путь к паке nodejs. Это делается так: Этот компьютер -> Свойства -> Дополнительные параметры системы -> Дополнительно -> Переменные среды -> Path -> Изменить и вручную дописать. А потом перезапустить консоль. Вот до перезапуска консоли я долго догадывался