# node.js не работает

Tags: node.js, npm

Ввожу команды в обычную консоль. Каждый раз выдаёт ошибку, что ни команды node, ни команды npm нет. Скриншот консоли прикреплён

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня стоит Windows 10 LTSC версии 1809

Comment: А что у вас в path? Пути выставлены правильно?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853394/node-не-является-исполняемой-программой

Comment: npm в PATH есть. Самого node.js нет, так что сейчас добавлю, спасибо!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Node не является исполняемой программой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853394/node-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9)